# Fiona Geometry Error 12L when opening geodatabase

Tags: file-geodatabase, fiona

I am trying to read a geodatabase using Fiona, but I keep coming across the error:

```
  fiona.errors.UnsupportedGeometryTypeError: 12L
```

Which I am very unsure why it is happening.

I've done the following background checks:

```
  fiona.supported_drivers:
  {'ESRI Shapefile': 'raw', 'OpenFileGDB': 'r', 'SUA': 'r', 'ARCGEN': 'r', 'GeoJSON': 'rw', 'GPKG': 'rw', 'Idrisi': 'r', 'GPX': 'raw', 'SEGY': 'r', 'BNA': 'raw', 'AeronavFAA': 'r', 'GPSTrackMaker': 'raw', 'DGN': 'raw', 'PCIDSK': 'r', 'MapInfo File': 'raw', 'DXF': 'raw'}

  Going_in = fiona.open(SourceDatabasePolygons) #this is the geodatabase
  print Going_in.meta
```

which gives:

```
  {'crs': {'init': u'epsg:28353'}, 'driver': u'OpenFileGDB', [//////OP 
  omitted///////]', 'schema': {'geometry': 'MultiPolygon',[//////OP 
  omitted///////]])}}
```

Multipolygon is listed as a possibly geometry type at [Fiona docs](https://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html#geometry-types).

When I open the database to check the data it does list the individual components as polygons (which are also supported).

I am completely at a loss as to why I can get it to work as I am attempting to get this segment of code to run:

```
  with fiona.open(SourceDatabasePolygons, layer=0) as Poly:
      with fiona.open(SourceDatabasePoints, layer=0) as F_Point:
              if shape(F_Point['geometry']).within(shape(Poly['geometry'])):  
                  print "true"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe worth trying to read it using the `OGR` to isolate the problem (that is, is it `fiona` related error or the `GEOS` related error)

Answer (score 3):

I have had this error too. I believe the culprits were a single multipolygon feature intersecting itself, and features with Bezier curves created in ArcMap. The former was resolved by correcting topology, and the latter was resolved by exporting the feature class to a shapefile and then importing it as a feature class back into the geodatabase.